# Nginx won't return 304

Tags: nginx, drupal, nginx-config, nginx-location

Trying to return 304 on Nginx (see following response).

Nginx 1.2, PHP FPM 7.4.

Is there any other thing I am missing?. There is no reverse proxy.

Location Block is as following:

```
location ~* ^.+\.(?:css|cur|js|jpe?g|gif|htc|ico|png|html|otf|ttf|eot|woff|woff2|svg)$ {

    access_log off;
    expires max;
    gzip_static on;

    ## fell swoop.
    tcp_nodelay off;
    ## Set the OS file cache.
    gunzip on;
    open_file_cache max=3000 inactive=120s;
    open_file_cache_valid 45s;
    open_file_cache_min_uses 2;
    open_file_cache_errors off;
    add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;

}
```

Server Response

```
 server: nginx
 date: Tue, 30 May 2023 04:20:04 GMT
 content-type: image/png
 content-length: 9532
 last-modified: Tue, 30 May 2023 01:01:27 GMT
 vary: Accept-Encoding
 etag: "64754ae7-253c"
 expires: Thu, 31 Dec 2037 23:55:55 GMT
 cache-control: max-age=315360000
 strict-transport-security: max-age=31536000
 x-content-type-options: nosniff
 x-content-options: nosniff
 accept-ranges: bytes
```